# Neural network back propagation weight change effect on predictions

Tags: networking, neural-network

I am trying to understand how neural network can predict different outputs by learning different input/output patterns..I know that weights changes are the mode of learning...but if an input brings about weight adjustments to achieve a particular output  in back propagtion algorithm.. won't this knowledge(weight updates) be knocked of when presented with a different set of input pattern...thus making the network forget what it had previously learnt..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to avoid "destroying" the networks current knowledge is to set the *learning rate* to a sufficiently low value.

Lets take a look at the mathmatics for a perceptron:

[image: Weight updates in the backpropagation algorithm]

The learning rate is always specified to be < 1. This forces the backpropagation algorithm to take many small steps towards the correct setting, rather than jumping in large steps. The smaller the steps, the easier it will be to "jitter" the weight values into the perfect settings.

If, on the other hand, used a learning rate = 1, we could start to experience trouble with converging as you mentioned. A high learning rate would imply that the backpropagation should always prefer to satisfy the currently observed input pattern.

Trying to adjust the learning rate to a "perfect value" is unfortunately more of an art, than science. There are of course implementations with adaptive learning rate values, refer to this [tutorial from Willamette University](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/momrate.html). Personally, I've just used a static learning rate in the range [0.03, 0.1].

Comment: I grab your concepts..but if for instance with with a perfect learning rate i present the the network with inputs x1 to bring about weight adjustments w1,will further changes in weight adjustments w2 by inputs x2 not make the network "forget" its output for x1 since weights adjustment w1 has changed to w2

Comment: Well, you are actually correct! If the input signals were forced to compete for the weight adjustment, the algorithm would never converge! Lets say you have a dataset like [ input, target ] of { [ (1,1), (**1**) ], [ (1,1), (**0**) ] }, the weight adjustments will counteract each other. Albeit, this should "never" happen in your dataset.